# How to mount an USB disk attached to a NAS

Tags: debian

I tried and failed mounting an USB drive attached to a NAS.

I’ve created those directories:

```
   sudo mkdir -p //mnt/rsynclacie
   sudo chown -R osmc:osmc /mnt/rsynclacie

   sudo mkdir -p //mnt/rsyncsam
   sudo chown -R osmc:osmc /mnt/rsyncsam
```

Then in /etc/fstab I have those 2 lines:

```
//192.168.1.18/OpenShare /mnt/rsynclacie cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,rw,uid=1000,_netdev 0 0
//192.168.1.18/SAMSUNG/LacieBU/ /mnt/rsyncsam cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,rw,uid=1000,_netdev 0 0
```

I can mount OpenShare directory using:

```
mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.18/OpenShare /mnt/rsynclacie
```

But

```
mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.18/SAMSUNG/LacieBU /mnt/rsyncsam
```

fails and I don’t see why.
Any idea?

EDIT:
Maybe a clue:
command

```
smbtree -U osmc
```

gives:

```
WORKGROUP
     \\OSMC                          Samba 4.2.10-Debian
             \\OSMC\IPC$             IPC Service (Samba 4.2.10-Debian)
             \\OSMC\usbstorage       USB
             \\OSMC\pishare          Pi Share
             \\OSMC\print$           Printer Drivers
     \\NETWORKSPACE2                 NetworkSpace2
             \\NETWORKSPACE2\IPC$            IPC Service (NetworkSpace2)
             \\NETWORKSPACE2\MyShare
             \\NETWORKSPACE2\OpenShare
             \\NETWORKSPACE2\SAMSUNG (usb)
             \\NETWORKSPACE2\osmc
             \\NETWORKSPACE2\rsync
```

`\\NETWORKSPACE2\SAMSUNG (usb)` can be seen.

But
how can I point to 
`//192.168.1.18/SAMSUNG (usb)`…
in fstab?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the share name is therefore `SAMSUNG (usb)` you should be able to replace the spaces
by `\040` (the octal code for space) in the fstab entry, eg:

```
//192.168.1.18/SAMSUNG\040(usb)/LacieBU/ /mnt/rsyncsam cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,rw,uid=1000,_netdev 0 0
```

Comment: Hum… it still gives an error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' (usb) parenthesis?

Comment: try replacing the `(` and `)` chars by their octal escape: `\050` and `\051` respectively.

Comment: Thank you meuh. No syntax error now, but… another error: "mount error(6): No such device or address" ?

Comment: perhaps there are more spaces in the share name? Try piping your `smbtree` command output through `cat -vet`. It will show the end of the line with a `$`. Make sure there are no extra chars before it on the samsung line.

Comment: not sure I understood what you’re saying, but smbtree `cat -vet` gives               \\NETWORKSPACE2\IPC$            IPC Service (NetworkSpace2)
                \\NETWORKSPACE2\MyShare
                \\NETWORKSPACE2\OpenShare
                \\NETWORKSPACE2\SAMSUNG (usb)
                \\NETWORKSPACE2\rsync
                \\NETWORKSPACE2\osmc
with no extra space…

Comment: I meant do `smbtree -U osmc|cat -vet`. I had a quick try with a linux samba server using a share with the same name as you have, "SAMSUNG (usb)", and managed to mount it ok using the escape chars you tried in the fstab on a raspberry pi. Obviously, this is not the same software as in your case, but that's all I can try, sorry. Perhaps you can try working at the NAS end to get the share renamed (in a new posted question)?

Comment: Unfortunately It can’t be changed ( and I didn’t find any extra space with the command and, on my side, `//192.168.1.18/SAMSUNG\040\050usb\051/LacieBU/ /mnt/rsyncsam cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,rw,uid=1000,_netdev 0 0` still unreachable. Thanks for having helped Monsieur Meuh.

Answer (score 0):

To those who has the same issue I finally resolve by adding quotes this way:

```
mount -t cifs -o guest "//192.168.1.18/SAMSUNG (usb)/LacieBU" /mnt/rsyncsam
```